# Convert a time(in string) , eg. 1:00 IST to another timezone(say in PST)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have need to convert a time "02:24:17CDT" of TZ name "US/Central" to one or more tz(s) say Asia/Kolkata,America/Regina.

Comment: You can use [moment js](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Javscript doesn't have timezones defined, except the local timezone and UTC.
You can read more here:https://nulogy.com/who-we-are/company-blog/articles/dealing-with-timezones-in-javascript/

You will have to build your own. You can create an object with all timezones defined, like this:

```js
var timeZones = {
  CET : +1,
  UTC: 0
}
```

Now when you have a time, convert it to UTC by subtracting the offset, then to your timezone by adding the offset.